# Using jQuery .show .hide function with asp.net MultiView

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-tabs, summary, multiview

I am using asp multiview at the end of my form to view a summary page prior to submitting to the sql server.    My problem is that I have a few show/hide jQuery functions if a check box is selected.  Well, after going to the summary and clicking edit, it goes back and causes some issues with the .show .hide function.   Below is a bit of my jQuery code I am using.   Ultimately, I would like to keep the state chosen by the end user (checked or unchecked).   Am I going about this the wrong way?

If I choose to not use asp multiview, and use jQuery .tabs instead, how would I get data from a text input to a value in a summary page?

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function uncheck() {
        // Uncheck all checkboxes on page load    
        $("input:checkbox:checked").attr("checked", false);
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.emsSection').hide();
        $('#emsYES').click(function () {
            $('.emsSection').show();
        });
        $('#emsNO').click(function () {
            $('.emsSection').hide();
        });
        $('.thirdPartyForm').hide();
        $('#thirdPartyService').click(function () {
            var chk = $(this);
            $('.thirdPartyForm').fadeToggle('fast', chk.attr('checked'));
        });
        $(".phoneMask").mask("(999) 999-9999");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your JavaScript inside function pageload instead of document.ready

Does that solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

my solution was to use jQuery cookie plugin.   After doing a bit a research, I figured it out by creating the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('.thirdPartyForm').hide();

        if ($.cookie('showhide') == 'showtp') {
            $('.thirdPartyForm').show();
        }

        $('#thirdPartyService').click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $(".thirdPartyForm").show();
                $.cookie('showhide', 'showtp');
            }
            else {
                $(".thirdPartyForm").hide();
                $.cookie('showhide', null);
            };
        });
        $('.emsSection').hide();

        if ($.cookie('emsservice') == 'showems') {
            $('.emsSection').show();
            }

            $('#emsYES').click(function () {
                $('.emsSection').show();
                $.cookie('emsservice', 'showems');
            });
            $('#emsNO').click(function () {
                $('.emsSection').hide();
                $.cookie('emsservice', null);
        });
    });
```